# Mysql optimization without this subquery and without limit offset

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

How can optimize this query without using the sub select queries ? also for the pagination as being told not to use the limit 0,0 .

```
  select 
      e.logo,  e.id,  r.id,  r.userid, u.username,  u.fullname, e.push_notificaciones, e.nombre, r.reservationdate,  u.userphoto,  s.direccion, 
 r.comment, r.restcomment, r.status,  r.phonenumber, u.email, 
(select  u.fullname from users u where  parseID = r.approvalbyuserid) as approvalfullname, 
( select  u.userphoto from users u where  parseID = r.approvalbyuserid ) as approvaluserphoto 
    from 
      users u, 
      reservations r, 
      empresas e, 
      sucursales s 
    where 
      r.userid = 'AEnStpQk4B' 
      and e.id = r.restid 
      and u.parseID = r.userid 
      and s.id = r.sucursalid 
    limit 
      0, 
      20
```

Comment: Sorry to see that you must deal with such an old query. We can see from the join syntax that this was probably written in the beginning of the 1990s, maybe earlier. I suggest you first fix this and use proper ANSI joins (`from users u inner join reservations r on r.userid = u.parseID`). Then add another join to get the approval user (`left join users u2 on u2.parseID = r.approvalbyuserid`).

Comment: As to `LIMIT 0, 0`: why would you even use it? It returns zero rows. Well, you'd get to know columns and types, but why not select data with that information right away?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rewrite this as

```
SELECT 
   e.logo,  e.id,  r.id,  r.userid, 
   u.username,  u.fullname, e.push_notificaciones, 
   e.nombre, r.reservationdate,  u.userphoto,  s.direccion, 
   r.comment, r.restcomment, r.status,  r.phonenumber, u.email, 
   a.fullname as approvalfullname, 
   a.userphoto as approvaluserphoto 
FROM reservations r
JOIN users u ON u.parseID = r.userid 
JOIN users a ON a.parseID = r.approvalbyuserid
JOIN empresas e ON e.id = r.restid 
JOIN sucursales s ON s.id = r.sucursalid 
WHERE 
   r.userid = 'AEnStpQk4B' 
LIMIT 0, 20
```

As long as all values in users exist. If not, you might need a `LEFT JOIN`

For pagination, the first number for LIMIT should be:

```
number_of_lines_per_page*(page_num -1)
```

SO for 20 items per page, for page 3:

```
LIMIT 20*(3-1), 20
```

If however, you want to get all results without any limit and handle it in your display code, just skip the `LIMIT` line

Comment: one commment thought, i just saw that if a user without parseID it will take that user... :/

Comment: Modified . LEFT JOIN users a ON a.parseID = r.approvalbyuserid and a.parseID IS NOT NULL and a.parseID != ''